# Convert EDI 850 to JSON/CSV format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, edi

I have a EDI 850 file which I want to convert it into JSON or CSV file using nodejs.

Here is my sample ED I850 file

```
ISA*01*0000000000*01*0000000000*ZZ*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO*ZZ*123456789012345*101127*1719*U*00400*000003438*0*P*>
GS*PO*4405197800*999999999*20101127*1719*1421*X*004010VICS
ST*850*000000010
BEG*00*SA*08292233294**20101127*610385385
REF*DP*038
REF*PS*R
ITD*14*3*2**45**46
DTM*002*20101214
PKG*F*68***PALLETIZE SHIPMENT
PKG*F*66***REGULAR
TD5*A*92*P3**SEE XYZ RETAIL ROUTING GUIDE
N1*ST*XYZ RETAIL*9*0003947268292
N3*31875 SOLON RD
N4*SOLON*OH*44139
PO1*1*120*EA*9.25*TE*CB*065322-117*PR*RO*VN*AB3542
PID*F****SMALL WIDGET
PO4*4*4*EA*PLT94**3*LR*15*CT
PO1*2*220*EA*13.79*TE*CB*066850-116*PR*RO*VN*RD5322
PID*F****MEDIUM WIDGET
PO4*2*2*EA
PO1*3*126*EA*10.99*TE*CB*060733-110*PR*RO*VN*XY5266
PID*F****LARGE WIDGET
PO4*6*1*EA*PLT94**3*LR*12*CT
PO1*4*76*EA*4.35*TE*CB*065308-116*PR*RO*VN*VX2332
PID*F****NANO WIDGET
PO4*4*4*EA*PLT94**6*LR*19*CT
PO1*5*72*EA*7.5*TE*CB*065374-118*PR*RO*VN*RV0524
PID*F****BLUE WIDGET
PO4*4*4*EA
PO1*6*696*EA*9.55*TE*CB*067504-118*PR*RO*VN*DX1875
PID*F****ORANGE WIDGET
PO4*6*6*EA*PLT94**3*LR*10*CT
CTT*6
AMT*1*13045.94
SE*33*000000010
GE*1*1421
IEA*1*000003438
```

How can I convert it into CSV or JSON format? Is there any parser available to parse the above file?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it will help you, node parsers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/edi-parser;
https://github.com/pagarme/edipsy

Comment: Note that stackoverflow discourages library & other software recommendations as they tend to be opiniated and allowing them can attract spam. A comment asking OP whether he considered using one of the existing nodejs EDI parser might have been preferable.

Comment: I have tried these libraries however they don't work well for the above example file

Comment: @HarshMakadia could you please share how did you do the conversion then?

Comment: @Gayathri - I had used a 3rd PARTY API to achieve this.

Comment: @HarshMakadia May I know what 3rd PARTY API is it?

Comment: @HarshMakadia - do you remember what 3rd party API you used?  thanks!