# Convert JSON to edi 850

Tags: edi

Is it possible to convert JSON to edi 850.

[Convert EDI 850 to JSON/CSV format in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56680494/convert-edi-850-to-json-csv-format-in-javascript)

On the above edi 850 is converted to JSON, is it possible to convert back to 850 after some changes on JSON files like order status or line items etc.

Comment: Just do two step. Convert JSon to some object of your class representing order, then convert this object into `EDI 850`. This is proper way to do it.

Comment: @marekr do you know if this already exist? Don't want to reinvent the wheel if already exists pls . Some example will help .

Comment: @eppye any ideas pls . I have been using Bots , all others are working except this conversions

Comment: You might be interested in [stedi](https://stedi.com). See https://www.stedi.com/docs/guides/creating-edi-based-on-an-implementation-guide for details